# How to add an ActionListener to an anonymous object?

Tags: java, swing, object, actionlistener, anonymous

How can i add ActionListeners to the MemoryFeld objects in the nested for-loop ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        grid.add(new MemoryFeld(teile[k][i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MemoryFeld`?

Comment: a class which extends JButton, sorry I thought this was pretty obvious ?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a reference, add the actionlistener to the reference, then add the reference to the grid? Um, pretty obvious to who, _you_?

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it just like any other ActionListener

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        MemoryFeld thing = new MemoryFeld(teile[k][i]);
        thing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Will print out message and object to prove it's
                // different from the other ones
                System.out.println("This thing was pressed " + x);
            }
        }); 
        grid.add(thing);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you could create a function for MemoryFeld like so

```
public MemoryFeld addListener(ActionListener newListener) {
    this.addActionListener(newListener);
    return this;
}
```

This will allow you to do this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        grid.add(new MemoryFeld(teile[k][i]).addListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Will print out message and object to prove it's
                // different from the other ones
                System.out.println("This thing was pressed " + x);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

However, personally I think this is harder to read and doesn't really help anything.

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured it out myself but your answer is exactly where my fault was. I just had to make a reference variable in the for-loop for memoryFeld (as you did) and it worked perfectly fine. Nonetheless thank you very much for the answer !